# Don't know how to convert array to string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm a newbie when it comes to powershell

Can you guys help me how to get the result of an array to string?
My goal here is that the script will check the folder size and if the size is greater than or equal to the value declared then it will display the folder and location. I have a hard time getting the result to string so that I can have it display in our monitoring system

here is the script

```
$array= @() 
$folder = "<enter here the folder location>"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject  
    $Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).sum / 1000MB, 2)
            $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" $_.FullName 
            $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeGB" $Size 
            $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DateModified" $_.LastWritetime 
                if ($Size -ge  <threshold of foldersize>)
                    {
                    $array +=$obj 
                    }
    } 

 $array
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Powershell does a pretty good job displaying array contents. What's wrong with it? And what output exactly are you looking for? Ideally show us both current output and desired output.

Comment: take a look at the `-f` string format operator. [*grin*]

Comment: Folder size scripts already exist, all over the web, for you to use as-is or tweak as needed.  ['powershell get folder size'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+get+folder+size%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Show us the way your _monitoring system_ wants to display the data. Without knowing that, there is absolutely no point to this question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy with the default output, simply apply `| Out-String` to get the array as a string

For Example:

`$result = $array | Out-String`

If you'd like to just get a simple list of the paths without the additional metadata and headers, try something like this:

`$result = $array | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | Out-String`

Comment: Hello SBdev, I tried your example and yes it did gave me the output parameter I needed. the solution all along is to assign the $array | out-string to a variable